# Share to Pinterest via Share extension

Tags: ios, ios8, pinterest, ios8-share-extension

I am in the process of implementing share to Pinterest functionality in an iOS app. In the SDK, the API looks like this:

```
[pinterest createPinWithImageURL:@"http://placekitten.com/500/400"
           sourceURL:@"http://placekitten.com"
           description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
```

I was wondering if there is way to pass in the same information in the native iOS 8 Share Extension. I can only share the image directly or via a url, but I can't figure out how to provide the source url. There doesn't seem to be any recent Pinterest documentation for iOS 8. The [iOS documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/ios/)
page was last updated December 13, 2013. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: You can pass the image or image url directly, but you can also only pass in the source URL. It will fetch the page and let you choose the image to pin. It doesn't seem like you can add a description via the share extension.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for [NSExtensionItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSExtensionItem_Class/). You can make an `NSItemProvider` that returns your image, and also set `attributedContentText` on the `NSExtensionItem`. I haven't played around with Pinterest much, but that's the standard way of accepting extension items as a recipient.